# No multiplayer on total war?

Tags: steam, empire-total-war

I downloaded a total war game on steam today to play multiplayer but on the main menu is only allows for a single-player mode. Any way to fix this to allow local, online multiplayer? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: @131_aze OS Catalina10.15.7 (19H15)

Answer (score 1):

[From this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/totalwar/comments/f4jz7z/multiplayer_button_not_showing/): Mac OS 10.15+ is 64-bit only, and multiplayer is not available.

But, it links to [this Steam Community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/34030/discussions/0/1629665087689724502/) post from Feral, the company that ported it to Mac OS, with the top comment:

> Players using a version of OS X before 10.15 can access a compatible version of the game via the Beta tab in the game’s properties window. Select the ‘Mac_Retail_1.1 - macOS 10.14.6 or older only' branch for a version that is compatible with 10.9.5 up to 10.14.6.

So, you could try [multiple Mac OS installs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208891) to be able to use multiplayer.